# Can I scale the actual text in a TextView in Android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview, scaling

Is it possible to create [a scaled TextView like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWnLd.jpg) where the text itself is scaled in one direction? In the picture, the top half shows a basic TextView outlined in blue. The bottom half shows the same TextView after the scaling I'm trying to do. The height is the same but the width of the view has been cut in half.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible with a TextView using the default font. To accomplish the effect you are looking for you would probably have better luck creating and resizing an image or dynamically using a different font that has half the width per character.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the library [autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) from [grantland](https://github.com/grantland) in my projects.

The usage is simple.

```
<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    autofit:minTextSize="16sp"
/>
```

for example. The result is as follows.

[image: Autofit Textview Example]